# Set Toggle switch based on condition on page load

Tags: jquery, razor, slidetoggle

Here is my code -

```js
(function () {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            
            $('.switch-input').on('change', function () {
                var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
                var selectedData;
                var $switchLabel = $('.switch-label');
                if (isChecked) {
                    selectedData = $switchLabel.attr('data-on');
                } else {
                    selectedData = $switchLabel.attr('data-off');
                }
                if (selectedData === 'ACTIVE') {
                    selectedData = 'A';
                } else {
                    selectedData = 'C';
                }
                $('#h-status').val(selectedData);
                $('#form_filterBillItems').submit();
            });
        });

    })();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="switch">
                        <input class="switch-input" type="checkbox"/>
                        <span id ="tglInp" class="switch-label" data-on="CANCEL" data-off="ACTIVE"></span> <span class="switch-handle"></span>
                    </label>
```

I have this toggle switch that displays a filtered list based on the switch value : 'ACTIVE' or 'CANCEL'

This is on a Razor view. The grid that displays the list is in a partial view. But the toggle switch is on the full view.

The issue is when I return to this view, the grid is filtered based on the condition but the switch goes back to its default state. For example, if I go to the next view from Toggle switch state Cancel, when I return it should be still on Cancel but the toggle switch is on Active.

How do I do that. Any help would be highly appreciated! This is my first question, so if I made any mistakes, in posting, I apologize.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added another javascript function to check for the toggle switch value and change it based on the condition.

Here is my updated code -

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            var data = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewData["bi_status"]));
            if (data==='A'){ data = 'ACTIVE'; } else{ data = 'CANCEL'; }
           $('.switch-input').on('change', function () {...});
        });
    })();
    

    function setSwitch(args) {
        var $switchLabel = $('.switch-label');
        var $switchInput = document.getElementById('tglInp');
        var dataOn = $switchLabel.attr('data-on');
        var dataOff = $switchLabel.attr('data-off');
        if (args === 'CANCEL') {
            $switchInput.checked = true;
            $switchLabel.attr('data-on', dataOn);

        } else {
            $switchInput.checked = false;
            $switchLabel.attr('data-off', dataOff);
        }
    }
```

-- For anyone looking for an answer to a similar issue. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

First remove the unwanted duplicate code to narrow down the issue as below.
Check whether the selectedData is posted to controller action correctly and filtered data is returned to the view.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.switch-input').on('change', function () {

            var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');

            var selectedData;

            if (isChecked) {

                selectedData = 'A';

            } else {

                selectedData = 'C';

            }

            $('#h-status').val(selectedData);

            $('#form_filterBillItems').submit();

        });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't believe I have duplicate code. I need to get the value of selectedData from the 'data-on'/'data-off' attribute first, before I can check the value and pass that to the controller.

Comment: This part is working fine. What I am having trouble with is, when I return to this view, I need to have the switch be in the state that I left it before going to the next view. If I went from Cancel, it needs to be on Cancel and not on Active.

Comment: In jQuery, you can use localStorage and sessionStorage to store a current view value. Then next time when the view is returned from controller action, check for the storage value and then toggle it.